# Can't move my cursor when visual studio starts

Tags: visual-studio-2010

all

I just installed vs 2013 and started using it. However, after I lauched it, my mouse cursor couldn't move. I'm sure there is no problem with my mouse...

Could somebody plz give me any help?
Cheers!

Comment: Just forgot to mention that I got windows 7 system in my PC

Answer (score 0):

Open Task Manager and close `wisptis.exe`:

[image: Screenshot]